# Query foreign key and constraint's name of table in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that I can see relationship by create a diagram, however, I want to get all relationship's table in sqlserver database by using a query. Please share if you can! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to get the relationship's table:

```
SELECT 
       OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) TableName,
       COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id) ColName
    FROM 
       sys.foreign_keys AS f
    INNER JOIN 
       sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc 
          ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
    INNER JOIN 
       sys.tables t 
          ON t.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
    WHERE 
       OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) = 'YourTableName'
```